# multi-threading: thread gets own copy of method, but parameter is shared

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, static-members, instance-variables

I want to confirm my understanding on this -

```
public class Main {

    private static int j = 0;
    private int k = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main obj = new Main();
        obj.doProcess();
    }

    public void doProcess() {
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            service.submit(new SingleProcessor());
        }
    }

    public static void myStaticMethod() {
        System.out.println("my static method");
        int i = 0;
        i++;
        j++;
        System.out.println("i " + i);
        System.out.println("j " + j);
    }

    public void myInstanceMethod() {
        System.out.println("my instance method");
        int i = 0;
        i++;
        k++;
        System.out.println("k " + k);
    }

    private class SingleProcessor implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("single run starts" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            myStaticMethod();
            myInstanceMethod();
        }

    }
}
```

When a thread runs, it gets it's own copy of methods, be it static or instance method - any variable created inside these methods are local and specific to that thread. It's like multiple 'instances' of this method are getting executed simultaneously, any variable created inside is not shared (it's local).

However parameters (static or instance) are shared by threads.

So in above example -
i is local and specific to thread.
j is shared.
k is shared.

output -

```
single run startspool-1-thread-1
single run startspool-1-thread-2
my static method
single run startspool-1-thread-3
my static method
i 1
i 1
j 2
j 2
my instance method
my instance method
k 1
k 2
my static method
i 1
j 3
my instance method
k 3
single run startspool-1-thread-4
my static method
i 1
j 4
my instance method
k 4
```

Is my understanding 100% correct? Anyone would like to put it in better words?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I followed correctly-- that should be correct.

Its the basic understanding of stack vs heap. Anything declared on the stack (variables declared in a function) is only available locally. Variables declared on the heap can be access globally or by any function within its scope.

So if you have a thread processing a function all the variables inside the function can only be accessed within that function. BUT if you have a global variable and two threads both threads can access that variable. The catch is that you have to make sure they don't override one another if they write to that variable.

The solution for this is locking a heap variable while one thread is read/writing to it and then unlocking it when its done.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think would happen if you run the code below? You'll see a similar output, but in different order, probably.  `i` is a static variable and is in static scope, `j` is in method scope, `k` is an instance variable of `Main`. Same stuff with threads. Scopes work the same with threads. You should read about inner classes instead.

```
public class Main {

    private static int j = 0;
    private int k = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Main obj = new Main();
        obj.doProcess();
    }

    public void doProcess() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            SingleProcessor sp = new SingleProcessor();
            sp.run();
        }
    }

    public static void myStaticMethod() {
        System.out.println("my static method");
        int i = 0;
        i++;
        j++;
        System.out.println("i " + i);
        System.out.println("j " + j);
    }

    public void myInstanceMethod() {
        System.out.println("my instance method");
        int i = 0;
        i++;
        k++;
        System.out.println("k " + k);
    }

    private class SingleProcessor implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            System.out.println("single run starts" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
            myStaticMethod();
            myInstanceMethod();
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're right.

A static variable could be intrepreted as a Singleton in your application, no matter how many Threads you have, they'll always have a reference to the same variable.

As for your instance variable **'k'**, it only works because your nested class is not static, which means you **need** an instance of **Main** to be able to instanciate **SingleProcessor**. Your instance of **SingleProcessor** will, under the hood' have a hidden variable referencing you **Main** instance. It's the same as if you'ld write this:

```
public class SingleProcessor implements Runnable {

    private Main main;

    public SingleProcessor(Main main){
        this.main = main;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("single run starts" + Thread.currentThread().getName());
        Main.myStaticMethod();
        this.main.myInstanceMethod();
    }

}
```

And give all of your **SingleProcessor** the same **Main** instance.

---

All of this is dangerous, a Thread may acquire a variable the *same time* another Thread is modifying it. There's alot of advanced topics about Thread safety. For simple types, you can use Atomic variables, se [Concurrency package JavaDoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/package-summary.html).

Comment: I don't think comparing a static variable with a singleton is a good idea. The fact that static variables are used for singleton is a way of doing it. A static variable can be changed if it's not final. Additionally, I don't think the answer go to the point (e.g. discussing stack vs heap)

Comment: Probably right, I shouldn't use the word Singleton. I tried to make a 'metaphore', to show that in memory, the same reference will be used by any thread. It can be confusing.

Comment: thats not true. a static variable is not treated differently by the memory model of java. threads will get a copy of that too and without synchronization visibility of the latest update is not guaranteed

Comment: Not sure to understand what you're saying... every thread will reference the same memory location, which reference another *single* memory location (the real *object* threads will want to use). For sure the latest can change in time, but it'll change for every thread, they won't have their copy, unless they explicitly keep a reference to it. We're assuming we're talking about a single classloader though